# ViewPager triggered onClick Event but not MotionEvent.ACTION_UP in HUAWEI phones

Tags: android, android-viewpager, handler

```
    viewPager.setOnTouchListener(
            new View.OnTouchListener() {


                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                    if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        moved = false;
                        System.out.println("clicked ACTION_DOWN");
                    }
                    if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                        System.out.println("clicked ACTION_MOVE");
                        moved = true;
                    }
                    if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        if (!moved) {
                            System.out.println("clicked ACTION_UP");
                            view.performClick();
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }

            }

    );
```

And added onclick listener as below

```
viewPager.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                                            }
                }
        );
```

It works fine in samsug mobiles but MotionEvent.ACTION_UP is not triggered in HUAWEI phones. Can anyone help?

Comment: You mean action move and down could be detected in HUAWEI phones?

Comment: Yes only ACTION_UP is not detected.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using GestureDetector

```
GestureDetector tapGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getActivity(), new TapGestureListener());
```

Use below code to handle this:

```
class TapGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener{

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            // Your Code here
            System.out.println("hello");
                            if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                                moved = false;
                                viewPager.performClick();
                                System.out.println("clicked ACTION_DOWN");
                            }
                            if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                                System.out.println("clicked ACTION_MOVE");
                                moved = true;
                            }
                            if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                                if (!moved) {
                                    System.out.println("clicked ACTION_UP");

                                }
                            }
                            return false;
                        }

        }
    }
```

The setOnclickListener will work properly here

```
viewPager.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                                            }
                }
        );
```